# An $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for difference between powers of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Question 15 of Chapter 1 of Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis, Ed. 2*

> Given $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\epsilon > 0$ show
> that for some $\delta > 0$, if $u \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|u-y| < \delta$
> then $|u^n-y^n| < \epsilon.$
>
> Hint: Prove the inequality when $n=1$,
> $n=2$, and then do induction on $n$ using the identity
> $u^n - y^n = (u-y)(u^{n-1} + u^{n-2}y + \dots +y^{n-1}).$

The question seems to be asking that the function $u \mapsto |u^n -y^n|$ is continuous for all $y,n$. I don't quite understand why the hint is to use induction.  Can this not be solved by direct means?

Namely, if $y < u < (y^n + \epsilon)^{1/n}$, then $u^n - y^n < (y^n + \epsilon) - y^n = \epsilon$, which gives the required $\delta$. Is there something wrong the proof that I have outlined, so that induction is needed?

Comment: No, the question is asking to prove that $u\mapsto u^n$ is continuous. The $y$ is just a point where the map is supposed to be continuous.

Comment: That makes sense. It seems to me that the proposed solution still remains reasonable, however, unless there is an error in the reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case $n=2$ follows from

$$|u^2 - y^2|=|u-y||u+y|\leq |u-y|(|u| + |y|) \leq |u-y|(2|y| + |u - y|).$$

Similarly, we see that

$$|u^n - y^n|=|u-y|\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}{y^{n-k} u^{k-1}}\right|$$

and

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}{y^{n-k}u^{k-1}}\right|\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}{|y^{n-k}||u^{k-1}|}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}{|y^{n-k}|(|y^{k-1}|+|u^{k-1}-y^{k-1}|)}.$$

Now the conclusion follows from induction.

Comment: Thank you for outlining the inductive argument. However, are you sure my reasoning is showing $|u-y|^n < y^n + \epsilon$?

Comment: I misunderstood. Your argument is correct if $0<y<u$ but will be at best  complicated if $y<0<u$. I think the inductive solution is more straightforward in this case.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. In the proof for $n=2$, is it correct that, given a desired $\epsilon >0$, one would have to solve for $\delta = |u-y|$ in the quadratic equation $|u-y|(2|y|+|u-y|) < \epsilon$?

Comment: Of course it is one of the solution but you can choose an easier bound like $\delta = \min(\epsilon/4|y|,\sqrt{\epsilon/2})$.